# ASP.NET MVC Multiple Actions for one job

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I am just starting out learning MVC and was wondering if I should use multiple actions in my controller or just one to achieve a simple registration page.

Should I do something like this (Multiple actions):

HTML (RegisterForm)

```
    <form action="CheckRegistration" method="post">
       Username:
        <input type="text" name="username"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult RegisterForm()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult CheckRegistration()
    {
        bool success = true;

        // Create User Object and populate it with form data
        User currentUser = new User();
        currentUser.Username = Request.Form["username"].Trim().ToString();

        // Validate Registration
        // code

        // Add user to database
        // code

        if (success)
        {
            return View("Login");
        }else
        {
            return View("RegistrationSuccess");
        }
    }
```

or this (Single action):

HTML (Register)

```
    <form action="Register" method="post">
       Username:
        <input type="text" name="username"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        bool success = true;
        String otherData = ""

        // Create User Object and populate it with form data
        User currentUser = new User();
        currentUser.Username = Request.Form["username"].Trim().ToString();

        // Validate Registration
        // code

        // Add user to database
        // code

        if (success)
        {
            return View("Login");
        }else
        {
            return View("Register", otherData);
        }
    }
```

With the first way I thought of, it has multiple actions and separates it into multiple steps.

The second way uses one actions so when Register view is called the first time, it won't add a user to the database since validation fails and will just return the View().

Which way is better from a professional standpoint (better) or are these both bad ways and there is a better way.

Comment: What would prevent you from registering a user in one fail swoop?

Comment: You need a `[HttpGet]` method and a `[HttpPost]` method, but they can be the same name `[HttpGet]public ActionResult Register()` and `[HttpPost]public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)`

Comment: But you need to go to the MVC site and learn the basics of MVC, in particulat how to use model in you view, and use the HtmlHelper methods to strongly bind to your model.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a simple view and do login in the post.

```
    // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use same name method in `MVC`.

1) Declare First method As **`[HttpGet]`** so it will return View and

2) Declare Second Method As **`[HttpPost]`**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult RegisterForm()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RegisterForm()
{
    bool success = true;
    String otherData = ""

    // Create User Object and populate it with form data
    User currentUser = new User();
    currentUser.Username = Request.Form["username"].Trim().ToString();

    // Validate Registration
    // code

    // Add user to database
    // code

    if (success)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("RegisterSuccess");
    }else
    {
        return View("RegisterForm");
    }
}
```